# How to make pagination in AngularJS?

Tags: html, angularjs, navigation

I'm developing a web application using the JavaScript framework "AngularJS".
I tried to learn it from the tutorials on "youTube". Indeed, I try to display the list of users per page, ie: page 1 contains 10 users. So we will have a pagination on the web page like this
 (I do not know how to do it).

-code to AngularJS:

```
    app.controller("UsersController",function($scope,$http)
            {
    $scope.ListUsers=[];
    $scope.pageNow=0;
    $scope.message = "";


    $scope.AllUsers=function()
    {
        $http.get("http://localhost:8080/ListUsers/"+$scope.pageNow)
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.ListUsers=data;    
            $scope.pages=new Array(data.totalpages);
        }).error(function(err){
            console.log("error:" +err);
        }); 
    };

    $scope.AllUsers();

 //Navigation between pages
   $scope.gotoPage=function(p)
   {
   $scope.pageNow=p;
   if ($scope.motCle == null){ 
        $scope.AllUsers();
     } else { 

      $scope.AllUsers();
     }
   };

};
```

- Code HTML:

> ```
> <div ng-repeat="user in ListUsers">
> Name:{{user.Name}}
> Email:{{user.Email}}    </div>
>
> //here pagination    
> <ul><li ng-class="{active:$index==pageNow}" class="clickable"
>       ng-repeat="p in pages track by $index">
>       <a ng-click="gotoPage($index)">{{$index}}</a></li>
> </ul>
> ```

-I have as a result that all the information is well displayed and pagination like this: 0-1-2-3-4-5

I then try to limit the display of the numbers of the pages by adding the navigation of "previous" and "next" ( << 1-2-3 >>)

Thank you,

Comment: pagination involves handline a lot of scenarious, i would suggest some third party modules already written, you can google for dirPaginate in angular

Comment: I will see it thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I've found has been using [ui-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

Here's a [plnkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/eheFSh/) I found on google that shows how to set it up.

Comment: Thank you sir for your help,